# Preloading ViewPager Pages - because of lag

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, fragment, swipe

Is this possible to preload Fragments for ViewPager so that there's no lag when user swipes to next page? I've been trying two kinds of adapters but there's no use in switching from Fragmentstatepageradapter (I am using fragments to generate N pages) to fragmentpageadapter. I've got a lot of bitmaps to load in my pages. Setting viewpager offscreen pages doesn't help. Is there a way to preload them and inflate in backgdound? I know this is a silly question but I am a bit desperate about performance. Basically in my app when user scrolls to next page there is kind of lag, just between pages, and it's so annoying... Please help or point the right direction. I am targeting Gingerbread so I need to use that what Android Support gives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this possible to preload Fragments for ViewPager so that there's no lag when user swipes to next page?

Sure. Have your adapter preload the fragments. *You* are responsible for returning fragments in `getItem()` -- whether those are "preloaded" or not is *your* job.

That being said, your problem most likely is not with the fragments themselves, but something that the fragments are doing. For example, you "got a lot of bitmaps to load in my pages", and if you are doing work related to those on the main application thread (e.g., using `BitmapFactory`), you are causing your own lag.

So, instead of racing off to "preload" stuff, a talented programmer would find out *specifically what is causing the lag*, using tools like Traceview. Then, and only then, would a talented programmer start working on a fix.

Comment: Well, probably i'll have to agree with this. However I did profiling before, optimised Bitmap loading as Google advised, reduced layouts complexity and so on. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Y.A.P.: Sorry, but your phrasing like "there is kind of lag" made it seem as though you had not done the profiling to determine the source of that lag.

Comment: Oh i haven't been precise, i know. This lag happens when bitmap is set to 6 ImageViews while adapter is generating the fragment. Bitmaps are optimised, only operation that happens in the main thread is filling Views with strings and bitmaps. The culprit is in native onDraw probably (which i didn't override).